# Golang: Get the pointer to a struct using reflection

Tags: go, recursion, reflection

I'm trying to write code that recursively traverses a struct and keeps track of pointers to all its fields to do basic analysis (size, number of references, etc). However, I'm running into an issue where I can't seem to get reflection to give me the pointer to a pure struct. I have the following code as an example:

```
type foo struct {
    A    *bar
    data []int8
}

type bar struct {
    B       *foo
    ptrData *[]float64
}

func main() {
    dataLen := 32
    refData := make([]float64, dataLen)

    fooObj := foo{data: make([]int8, dataLen)}
    barObj := bar{
        B:       &fooObj,
        ptrData: &refData,
    }
    fooObj.A = &barObj

    fooVal := reflect.ValueOf(fooObj)
    _ := fooVal.Addr().Pointer() // fails
    _ := fooVal.Pointer() // fails

    // More analysis code after this
}
```

If I wanted to traverse `fooObj`, that would be fine until I entered `barObj` at which point I again encounter `fooObj`. Because I don't have a way to get the pointer for the initial `fooObj` encounter, I end up traversing `fooObj` twice until I hit `barObj` the second time and exit the recursion. Any idea how to get a struct's pointer using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    A    *bar
    data []int8
}

type bar struct {
    B       *foo
    ptrData *[]float64
}

func main() {
    dataLen := 32
    refData := make([]float64, dataLen)
    
    // allocate here, now value has a pointer
    fooObj := &foo{data: make([]int8, dataLen)} 
    barObj := bar{
        B:       fooObj,
        ptrData: &refData,
    }
    fooObj.A = &barObj

    fooVal := reflect.ValueOf(fooObj)
    fmt.Println(fooVal.Pointer()) // succeeds

    // More analysis code after this
}
```

> Addr returns a pointer value representing the address of v. It panics if CanAddr() returns false. Addr is typically used to obtain a pointer to a struct field or slice element in order to call a method that requires a pointer receiver.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. You added a pointer to foo on declaration. It works here, but in my case, I don't know a priori what the data will look like and I can't impose any restrictions myself. If I have an embedded struct, or in this case, just a normal struct with no pointers, this solution isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

This takes a pointer of a value if it's possible.

```golang
package main

import "reflect"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    val := new(int)
    slice := []int{}
    local := 10
    fn := func() {}

    fmt.Println(PointerOf(val))
    fmt.Println(PointerOf(slice))
    fmt.Println(PointerOf(&local))
    fmt.Println(PointerOf(fn))
    fmt.Println(PointerOf(3))
}

func PointerOf(value any) (p uintptr, ok bool) {
    rValue := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    
    if(rValue.Kind() == reflect.Pointer || rValue.Kind() == reflect.Slice || rValue.Kind() == reflect.Func) {
        return rValue.Pointer(), true
    }    

    if(rValue.CanAddr()) {
        return rValue.Addr().Pointer(), true
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your code fails in this part

```
fooVal := reflect.ValueOf(fooObj)
_ = fooVal.Addr().Pointer() // fails
_ = fooVal.Pointer() // fails
```

In `foo` struct `data` is not a pointer value.

```
type foo struct {
    A    *bar
    data []int8
}
```

You are trying to call `reflect.Value.Addr().Pointer()` and `reflect.Value.Pointer()` on a non-pointer type, causing the error.

You can prevent this condition by checking if the type is actually `ptr`

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

type foo struct {
    A    *bar
    data []int8
}

type bar struct {
    B       *foo
    ptrData *[]float64
}

func main() {
    dataLen := 32
    refData := make([]float64, dataLen)

    fooObj := foo{data: make([]int8, dataLen)}
    barObj := bar{
        B:       &fooObj,
        ptrData: &refData,
    }
    fooObj.A = &barObj

    fooVal := reflect.ValueOf(fooObj)

    if fooVal.Kind().String() == "ptr" {
        _ = fooVal.Addr().Pointer() // ok
        _ = fooVal.Pointer()        // ok

       // More analysis code for pointer types
    } else {
       // More analysis code for non-pointer types
    }
}
```

Comment: @ddukki let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it doesn't solve the fundamental problem I'm having - that structs can't be referenced by pointer through reflections (or at all, it looks like). But it's increasingly looking like that's not really possible in Golang.